# Must declare scalar variable in If Exist SQL record in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I need help  with the code below. Whenever I run the code, I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@1"
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@2"

What is missing?

```
con = New SqlConnection(cs)
con.Open()          

Dim cb1 As String = "if exists (select Fedo from Mimos where Fedo=@1)" + "BEGIN " + "Update Mimos Set ActivationID=@2,Date=@3 where Fedo=@1)" + "END" + "Else" + "insert into Mimos (Fedo,ActivationID,Date) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3)"            

cmd = New SqlCommand(cb1)
cmd.Connection = con

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", Encrypt(TextBox1.Text.Trim))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", Encrypt(TextBox2.Text.Trim()))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", System.DateTime.Now)

cmd.ExecuteReader()

con.Close()
```

Comment: Your parametrized query text specifies `@1` instead of `@d1`. Same for `@2` and `@3`. Not sure of your exact intent.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type with @d1, @d2 and @d3

```
 con = New SqlConnection(cs)
    con.Open()          

    Dim cb1 As String = "if exists (select Fedo from Mimos where Fedo=@d1)" + "BEGIN " + "Update Mimos Set ActivationID=@d2,Date=@d3 where Fedo=@d1)" + "END" + "Else" + "insert into Mimos (Fedo,ActivationID,Date) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3)"            

    cmd = New SqlCommand(cb1)
    cmd.Connection = con

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", Encrypt(TextBox1.Text.Trim))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", Encrypt(TextBox2.Text.Trim()))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", System.DateTime.Now)

    cmd.ExecuteReader()

    con.Close()
```

Comment: Don't use `.AddWithValue`.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execut...`

Comment: If you surround your database objects with Using...End Using blocks then you don't have to worry about closing and disposing even if there is and error.